# Finding all callers of a function from the object file

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

What are the ways to find all callers (symbol names) of a particular function / symbol using only the compilation unit? How to find from a [compilation unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit) which library included in that unit was a symbol defined in?

Comment: What do you mean by "the compilation unit"? The .o file?

Comment: WIKI: [Compilation Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Compilation_Unit)

Comment: Well, considering that calls/references can also come from other compilation units, I'd say it's impossible.

Comment: Would debugging information compiled into the task not allow to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for calls to a function called `func` in an object file called `obj.o`, then:

```
objdump -dCS .text obj.o | grep func
```

Obviously, you can't find *incoming* calls this way.